# Override inherited @media queries

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm styling my own store through css.  I was using the "Presentation > 
I'm using a plugin in Wordpress that outputs a shop and I'm styling my own css for it.  The plugin has a built-in css so I'm overriding styles that are inherited through my css however the built-in css also has @media queries which differ from those on my site.

How can I invalidate/override the plugin's @media queries - I don't want to modify the plugin's built-in css and cause issues when I update.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to invalidate an entire media query that has already been loaded (though perhaps another answerer will prove me wrong, which would be great!). Once a stylesheet is loaded your only option is to create an identical media query that redefines any rules you want to override.

There are a few possible approaches when dealing with third party plugins that load CSS styles you wish to override:

1) Stop the plugin from loading its own CSS, and build its styles from scratch yourself. You can use its stylesheet as a starting point and remove/edit any rules and declarations you don't want.

2) Let the plugin load its own CSS styles, and override them in your stylesheet, like you are doing already. You will need to override the problematic media queries and styles contained within them.

3) Edit the plugin's CSS files directly. This is the most fragile option, since when you update the plugin your changes will be overwritten.

The approach you choose will probably be informed by how much of the original plugin styling you want to keep, and how much you want to remove. If you are only re-defining a handful of rules then Option 2 is a good approach. If you need to hack the original stylesheet to pieces then option 1 will be less of a maintenance nightmare.

You raise the issue of forwards compatibility: what happens when the plugin is updated with a new stylesheet? There is no simple answer to that question.  As I mentioned already, Option 3 has inherent problems in this respect, but the other options have their own pitfalls. Most plugin authors are good at keeping their styling hooks consistent between releases, and in my experience any changes you have made will continue to work between releases. But the bigger the third party library, the greater the chance of breaking changes.

Full blown eCommerce plugins (think WooCommerce) are definitely a pain once you start hacking away at their styles. If you are building a full blown eCommerce site then my advice is to try and retain as much of the plugin's built in styles as you can, and override as few rules as possible.

Comment: Appreciate the long and thorough response but options 2 and 3 really restate what I mentioned in the question.  Options 1 and 3 are too invasive to the plugin re updating.

Comment: Sorry I can't give you the answer you were hoping for. I wanted to give you third option to consider (option 1), but I understand it might not suit your needs. I guess you'll have to overwrite the media query rule by rule then :(

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing :)  Tedious but if I modify the plugin I'll forget by the time I update it and wipe my changes so I think the time now is better invested.  Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `!important` with your CSS properties like `width: 100% !important;`

If it doesn't work target your elements with its parent element like if you want to edit `span.someclass` then target `p span.someclass` or `body span.someclass`

It will work hopefully !

Comment: The OP wants to invalidate/override a media query, not a selector.

Comment: OP Basically wants to override default styling with new styling so he can normally write media query as it should be and his selectors should be like this.. That was my point!

Comment: No that won't work Jawwad Rizwan.  As I said in the question "the built-in css also has @media queries which differ from those on my site" - it's testing for sizes that are different from mine.  The only way I could override them would be to test for the same sizes and that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve.